# Adding WithEvents to SerialPort object place on form in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, events, serial-port

I have added a SerialPort object onto a form I created in a VB.NET solution.  How do I add "WithEvents" to it, since I dragged it onto the form instead of creating it in code.  Is it even necessary to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dragging it onto the form automatically adds it to the designer generated code as `WithEvents` - it has to or you wouldn't be able to hook up events in the Events pane.  If you hit the "View All Files" toggle in the Solution Explorer you should be able to see the designer files.  Have a look in there and you will find where the IDE adds this code.

Comment: I did a "find in files" search and saw the WithEvents keyword!  Thanks!

Comment: Where is the "View All Files" toggle?

Comment: @gonzobrains  In the Solution Explorer panel, at the top - second button from the left

Comment: duh.  I don't know how I missed that.  I mostly used C#, so I didn't notice the designer-generated code was missing or else I would have checked it already.  Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @gonzobrains  I use both as well and there are a lot of silly differences like that, many of which can drive you nuts.